# Ionic 3 + laravel. issue with http request on server

Tags: laravel, post, ionic-framework

I'm developing a hybrid app with Ionic 3 and Laravel as Back-end. I had to host the backend on an online server (000webhost) to do some in-app testing, that's when it started my problems. Before hosting, using my computer as a server (localhost), I was able to make any type of request through Ionic providers. Using webhost hosting, I can only make GET requests, any other type of request give me the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error. Trying to make the same type of request using the postman it is processed successfully.

My configuration file cors.php is as follow:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

he route I'm trying to access:

```
Route::post ('ajudado/', 'AjudadoController@set_ajudado');
```

the provider method in Ionic:

```
set_ajudado(dados):Promise<any>
  {
    return this.http.post(this.url, dados).toPromise().then(function(data){
      return  data; 
   });
  }
```

Comment: Please try to add options method in allowedMethods array and try again hope it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to allow the `OPTIONS` method in your CORS rules.

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
```